# How do I make an Apache Camel Servlet request return immediately?

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-camel, background-process

I want a request to an Apache Camel Servlet to return immediately, but continue processing the request in a "background" thread.  I've tried several things, but it seems it still is processing a lot before returning.

```
from("servlet://my-endpoint")
            .threads()
            .process(exchange -> {
                exchange.getOut().setBody(doStuff(exchange.getHeaders()))
            })
            .multicast()
            .parallelProcessing()
            .recipientList(constant("direct:a,direct:b,direct:c"), ",")
            .ignoreInvalidEndpoints()
            .transform()
            .constant("OK");
```

I test using curl:

```
curl 'http://localhost:4000/my-app/camel/my-endpoint' -X POST --data 'myVar=bar&myOtherVar=foo'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Because you use multicast main thread is waiting for response.

You just do your stuff in different threads, but in synchronous mode.
If you'd like to make it completely asynchronous, use wireTap to another route endpoint at the very beginning.

Pseudo code logic:

```
main route:  
         from-> wireTap exchange ->to(process_endpoint) -> set immediate response.
process route: from(process_endpoint) -> do all stuff -> stop route.
```

Answer (score 1):

camel servlet supports async mode, take a look at camel documentation
http://camel.apache.org/servlet.html
Using Servlet 3.0 Async Mode

using wireTap is also an alternative.
http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html

Answer (score 1):

I got a [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633061/how-to-i-exclusively-send-to-started-camel-routes?noredirect=1#comment70468423_41633061) on using [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html) instead.  Turns out it works great:

```
from("servlet://my-endpoint")
  .process(exchange -> {
    Map body = doStuff(exchange.getIn().getHeaders()));
    ProducerTemplate template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();

    Arrays.asList("direct:a", "direct:b", "direct:c")
      .forEach(endpoint -> template.asyncSendBody(endpoint, body));
  });
```

**EDIT: Warning! After using asyncSendBody in production, the machine went out of PIDs pretty fast.  I'll have to figure out why Camel isn't releasing them...**