# How to I exclusively send to started Camel routes?

Tags: java, apache-camel

```
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() {
    from("servlet://myservlet")
      .multicast()
        .parallelProcessing().recipientList(bean(this))
      .end();
  }

  @RecipientList
  public List<String> route(String body) {
    return getContext().getRouteDefinitions().stream()
      .filter(i -> i.getStatus(getContext()).isStarted() && i.getId().startsWith("FOO"))
      .map(OptionalIdentifiedDefinition::getId)
      .collect(toList());
  }
}
```

When I debug, I see that `getContext().getRouteDefinitions()` is empty, even though the routes are actually started.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To your actual title: Camel provides a [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html) which you can use to send stuff to your routes. To your bean approach, refactor the `route(...)` method to an own bean and instead of calling `bean(this)` use `bean(YourBean.class)`. You can add a further `Exchange exchange` property to the method arguments and then retrieve the context via the injected exchange. [See also the section at `Using method call as recipient list`](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html)

Comment: @RomanVottner Thank you! Replacing `String body` with `Exchange exchange` in the `route()` signature, and fetching the context from that exchange did the trick.  I'll look into `ProducerTemplate` as well, that looks handy.

Answer (score 0):

[RomanVottner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633061/how-to-i-exclusively-send-to-started-camel-routes?noredirect=1#comment70468423_41633061) provided a lot of insight by suggesting using the context from the exchange, and using [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html).  Here's what I ended up with:

```
from("servlet://my-endpoint")
  .process(exchange -> {
    ProducerTemplate template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();

    exchange.getContext().getRouteDefinitions().stream()
      .filter(routeDef -> 
              routeDef.getStatus(getContext()).isStarted() && i.getId().startsWith("FOO"))
      .map(OptionalIdentifiedDefinition::getId)
      .forEach(endpoint ->
               template.asyncSendBody(endpoint, exchange.getIn().getBody()));
  });
```

**EDIT: Warning! After using asyncSendBody in production, the machine went out of PIDs pretty fast.  I'll have to figure out why Camel isn't releasing them...**